# Почему сервер блочит все запросы на admin-ajax.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Eсть мультисайт на Wordpress.
Если зайти на сайт через админку, все ajax запросы отправляются и все работает.
В другом случае сервер блочит все запросы к admin-ajax.php. (И самописные, и плагиновские).

Показывает ошибку 503.

В чем может быть причина? И почему при переходе на сайт с админки все работает?

Comment: Плагины "безопасности"?

Comment: @SeVlad Здравствуйте. Нет. Плагинов безопасности не установлено

Comment: Тогда вопросы к хостеру.

Comment: @SeVlad В респонсе приходит такое сообщение "С Вашего IP адреса зафиксирована активность вредоносных программ. Включение JavaScript позволит нам проверить,
что запрос производится человеком и отобразить страницу сайта."
Но js включен.  Думаете нужно обращаться к хостеру?

Comment: ВП сам по себе ничего не блокирует. Очевидно, что блокировка - либо ненужные плагины "безопасности"  либо настройки хостинга.